# Pure Data - Autotune - Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, puredata

I want to developp an "I'm T-Pain app" for mobile devices. The input is my voice, and the output is my voice autotuned. I heard about Pure Data to create the Autotune effect.

I'm using Icenium, i have to developp my app with HTML/CSS/Javascript.

So i wonder if Pure Data is compatible with Javascript ?

Comment: Please define what you mean by *autotune*.  Automatic pitch quantisation of vocals? Pitch shifting by a fixed amount?

Comment: @Marko I mean pitch shifting by fixed amount.

Comment: @Marko Have you got a solution for that ?

Comment: are you sure about "pitch shifting by a fixed amount"? there is nothing "tuned" to that. usually *autotune* refers to automatic (potentially variable) pitch quantisation.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to checkout [WebPd](https://github.com/sebpiq/WebPd) which is an implementation of Pd written in javascript.

note that this is only *Pd-vanilla*, if you need the nifty features of Pd-extended you'll be out of luck, as most of those features are implemented as "plugins" (that is compiled C-code).

alternatively, you might want to have a look into [libpd](http://libpd.cc/) which will allow you to use the Pure Data engine as a library in your C/ObjC/python/... application.

Comment: Thanks you , i've just downloaded an "autotune.pd". This afternoon i'll add it to the code provided . But do you think it'll work on mobile device ? :/

Comment: since i haven't written nor looked at `autotune.pd`, i have no clue.

Comment: ok ok, what i mean is : Is WebPd compatible with mobile device ?

Comment: what does "compatible with mobile devices" mean? it requires a recent browser (HTML5)

Comment: I'm using Icenium (PhoneGap like) , i have to developp my app with HTML/CSS/Javascript. I know that Web Audio API is only compatible with "IOS 6-7" so i wonder if WebPd will be compatible with "Android" and "Iphone".

Comment: iOS does not implement the "Web Audio API". it is implemented by your browser. WebPd should be running on all browsers supporting the Web Audio API, whether that is on iOS-42, Android or CP/M. if you don't have the Web Audio API, what is going to do the audio processing? HTML? CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Thomas, if this is what you're referring to (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_Data) then the answer would be no. Phonegap relies on JS,HTML and CSS for the base and you can also utilize plug-ins which are written in Objective C (iOS) and Java (Android). None of this has any reference to the "visual programming language in question".

Comment: Thanks for your answer , then do you know another way to apply Autotune effect on my voice with Javascript (compatible with mobile devices) ?

Comment: Cordova API currently does not have anything like that, nor it will. You would have to find or develop a custom Cordova plugin where you can accomplish everything.

Comment: I've found https://github.com/ederwander/PyAutoTune . Unfortunately it's developp in Python . But i also find http://www.skulpt.org/# which able to write Python in javascript. Do you think it's possible to have Autotune effect by this way ?